# Поле-выделение в Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, pygame, рисование

Я пытался сделать поле-выделение для своей будущей игры в pygame. Однако в процессе создания я наткнулся с проблемой, что pygame так просто не может создать прямоугольник, точка отсчета которого `(x, y)` начинается с: верхнего-правого угла / нижнего правого угла / нижнего левого угла.
Это очень мешает свободному движению мыши, которая создает такое поле.

Может быть вы можете посоветовать какие-нибудь ресурсы, решающие такую проблему?

Инициализация:

```python
import pygame
pygame.init()

A = 600
B = 400
 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((A, B))

FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

Anskle = False
the_first_pos = None
```

Основой код:

```python
while True:

    x_mouse, y_mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
```

''' Если левая кнопка мыши нажата и в тоже время не отпущена(проверяет последний elif)'''

```
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            the_first_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            Anskle = True

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if Anskle:
                pos = event.pos
 
                width = pos[0] - the_first_pos[0]
                height = pos[1] - the_first_pos[1]

                pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'green', pygame.Rect(the_first_pos[0], the_first_pos[1], width, height))
                pygame.display.update()
                screen.fill('black')

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1:
            Anskle = False
```

Желаемый результат:

[image: Полу выделение]

Comment: _очень мешает свободному движению мыши_ — это как?

Comment: И не понял, почему точка отсчета не слева-сверху?

Comment: Мешает свободному движению мыши - когда (вычитание изначальной позиции к нынешней ) дает отрицательный размер, из за чего при движении мыши влево (например), поле-выделение пропадает полностью, ведь переменная width стала отрицательной                                            
   Пример:        ~pygame.Rect(the_first_pos[0], the_first_pos[1], width, height))~.

Comment: Значит вам надо поменять логику кода.

Comment: Есть ресурсы( книги, сайты ) решения этой проблемы?

Comment: Tuhtr, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick, в каком смысле? Код достаточно компактен, ошибка не в консоли, а физическая, ее в вопрос не вставишь.

Comment: @Tuhtr, тут не ресурсы нужны (если так надо, почитайте книги по пигейму), тут нужно хорошо понимать как строятся подобные взаимодействия с курсором. В данном конкретном случае вам надо просто переписать отрезок кода так, чтобы в нем определялась диагональ движения мыши и для каждого конкретного случая релевантно вычислялись width и height.

Comment: Tuhtr, смысл таков: скопировать ваш код и запустить его. А затем посмотреть, что вы там написали. Вы хорошо прочитали информацию по ссылки, которую я вам указал?

Comment: S. Nick, ознакомился, спасибо

Comment: @Глеб, спасибо за решение в виде диагоналей (от точки курсора мыши при нажатии до самого положения мыши)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import pygame


pygame.init()

A = 600
B = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((A, B))
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

Anskle = False
the_first_pos = None

while True:
    x_mouse, y_mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            the_first_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            Anskle = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if Anskle:
                pos = event.pos
                width = pos[0] - the_first_pos[0]
                height = pos[1] - the_first_pos[1]

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
                x, y = the_first_pos[0], the_first_pos[1]
                w, h = width, height
                if w < 0:
                    w = -w
                    x = x - w
                if h < 0:
                    h = -h
                    y = y - h

                pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'green', 
                    pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h))                     # + x, y, w, h
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                pygame.display.update()
                screen.fill('black')

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1:
            Anskle = False
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за решение

Comment: @Tuhtr пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour